# After Django is updated from 1.8 to 2.0, the service cannot be started

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnZQe.png)

Django version 1.8 is normal. Update to version 2.0 and enter python manage.py   Runser pops up bug:__ init__ () missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_ After that, I added the property on to the models ForeignKey_ delete= models.CASCADE   . But it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Updating on major version changes throws in a lot of incompatibilities. It is better to read those first before deciding to move ahead.

For more info, checkout [Django 2.0 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.0/) for the list of breaking changes so that you may act accordingly